# Adding label in AutoML for text classification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text, vertex, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to create a text dataset in a `Pipeline` for a text classification but I believe I am doing it the wrong way or at least I don't get it. The csv passing only contains two columns `message` and `label` which is true or false.

Inside my pipeline I am creating dataset like this which I am not very sure how dataset is recognizing that column `label` is the independent variable.

```
dataset = gcp_aip.TextDatasetCreateOp(
    project = project # my project id,
    display_name = display_name # reference name,
    gcs_source  = src_uris # path to my data in gcs,
    import_schema_uri = aiplatform.schema.dataset.ioformat.text.single_label_classification, 
)
```

once created the dataset, i do training like this within the `Pipeline`

```
# training
model = gcp_aip.AutoMLTextTrainingJobRunOp(
    project = project,
    display_name = display_name,
    prediction_type = "classification",
    multi_label = False,   
    dataset = dataset.outputs["dataset"],
)
```

Not sure if creation and training is doing correctly since I never specified that `label` is my label column and needs to use `message` as a feature.

In vertex ai the dataset created look like this

[image]

But in my training section the results from the AutML, looks like this, dont know why, label with 0% is there, which makes me doubt about the insertion of the data

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if the `label` you are pertaining to is the `Labels` column in this sample screenshot https://i.imgur.com/GlOWzP7.png? And if the `message` you are pertaining to is the `Text`? The sample image I provided is the screenshot of the created Dataset on Vertex AI from a CSV file to be used on the Training.

Comment: @ScottB i edit the question to show what the data and the training looks like in the console UI

Answer (score 0):

In preparation of CSV file, you don't need to specify which column is the `feature` and the `label`. Vertex AI's AutoML automatically reads the first column as the `feature` and the second column as the `label`. You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#csv) for more details in preparation of CSV data.

Below is sample CSV file, all values under first column(column A) are detected to be the `feature` and all values under second column(column B) are the `labels`.
[image]

You might need to check your CSV file and search for the word **"label"** on your second column and replace it with either **"True"** or **"False"** since based on your given data, you are only trying to have 2 `labels` which are "True" and "False". In addition, if you find the word "label" on your 2nd column and it doesn't have a value on its first column, then you just need to just remove the word "label".

In your provided screenshot here, there is a 1 count for the word **"label"**, which means there is a "label" value existing on the 2nd column of your CSV data. [image]